# StackExchange API abused for traffic

Tags: discussion, api, search-engine

Innocents who Bing and Google for StackExchange/StackOverflow questions are not seeing Stack_ URL at the top of the search results.  The offenders (I presume) are using the StackExchange API and republishing content for their own benefit (Ad views, and click throughs, or attack vectors).

1. Is this a breach of their account/API usage agreement?
2. Should StackExchange be working their SEO magic to get a higher ranking?
3. Is there anything we can really do?

Offenders I've found today:

1. http://wenda.baba.io/
2. http://youku.io/
3. http://quabr.com/
4. http://tiku.io/
5. http://www.stackprinter.com/ (more legit than others)